# Chrome monitoring?

Tags: chrome

I’ve been asked to make a monitoring system for Chrome. My manager wants it to automatically apply when users sign in to Chrome (with our G Suite account) (even at home, on non-work computers),and to have the system run in Incognito mode. Is this possible, and if so, what software should we use for it?

Update: Now he wants it to be invisible to users. I strongly doubt that this is possible, but if there is any program that can do this, please let me know.

Additional details:
Chrome on Windows
Yes, he will allow data from his account to be stored.

Comment: First, the users would need to install this spyware in chrome on their home system. I think that's a questionable request and probably violates some privacy laws. That's neither here nor there, though. Has your manager considered that not everyone uses Chrome? There are quite a number of browsers out there. IMHO, his idea is ill-conceived and dangerous from a legal standpoint.

Comment: Apart from that, the question lacks details: on what OS? How much is the manager willing to pay? Will he allow access to data accumulated from his logons (including on his personal/home machines) to all users? Afraid the part with the non-work computers at home must be considered illegal in most places. By the way, what do you mean by "sign in to Chrome"?

Comment: Here’s his responses: 1. Enterprise Chrome policy (user-level) 2. The majority of people use Chrome. 3. Just go figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like you need a new boss. He doesn't have a firm grasp on legality or reality.Good luck.